# The Kessel Run Parsecs - Star Wars

Tags: star-wars

Han Solo was able to "make the Kessel Run in less than 12 parsecs" but how is it measured? Is it the distance spent out of hyperspace?

Comment: No sorry, I'm new to the website and haven't really checked out the other posts.

Comment: don't worry about it! The question is closed (no one can post answers) but it doesn't need to be deleted.  This way anyone who finds your question can be redirected to the 'original'. Keep posting good questions!

Comment: Thanks, I'm just beginning to work my way around this site. So far it seems incredibly useful!